# Google charts: x-axis switch to days after 24 hours

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

Is there an option to switch to days after 24 hours without manually specifing the format?

If you have data that is less than 5 days, the chart only displays hours, which is confusing for our users. Instead it should display the date for anything more than 24 hours and the hours for anything less.

I don't want to specify the format manually as the chart will be used in multiple countries where date formats differ.

Comment: No, do it manually

Comment: no standard option for this -- which chart type are you using?

Comment: @WhiteHat I'm using the Line Chart